# mysql join for logical operator

Tags: mysql, join

I want to use JOIN for logical operating only, and get all the rows of the selected table.

For example:

Task table:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+
| id   | name        | projectID |
+------+-------------+-----------+
| 1    | steal       | 3         |
| 2    | sell        | 2         |
| 3    | earn        | 1         |
+------+-------------+-----------+
```

project table:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+
| id   | name        | online    |
+------+-------------+-----------+
| 1    | stealing    | 1         |
| 2    | selling     | 1         |
| 3    | earning     | 0         |
+------+-------------+-----------+
```

Select all the tasks where the project is online(online = 1)

What I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `task` 
LEFT JOIN  `project` ON project.id = task.projectID && project.online =1
```

That results to all the rows from project and from task
But I only want the rows from task, and use the join for logical operating

Comment: use `inner join` or `where` clause

Answer (score 2):

Use the table name before `*` to select only rows for a specific table

```
SELECT `task`.* 
FROM  `task` 
INNER JOIN  `project` ON project.id = task.projectID 
                     AND project.online = 1
```

And use a `inner join`. See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I am entirely baffled as to why this was downvoted.  In a quite convoluted way, the OP is asking for an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `task` 
LEFT JOIN  `project` ON project.id = task.projectID WHERE project.online =1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this :

 SELECT T.* FROM  `task` T
 LEFT OUTER JOIN  `project` P ON P.id = T.projectID 
 WHERE P.online = 1
```